# How do I use a shell command to tar a list of files and folders with exclusions

Tags: linux, unix, shell

How do I tar a list of files and folders (all in the same directory) with the exclusion of a single directory (which contains a huge amount of data)

Comment: You've had an answer to this particular one, but I'll note that if your exclusion pattern is more complicated, you should look into the "find" command used with tar.

Comment: Using the "find" command with tar only works if you don't have a large file list, otherwise you get "Argument list too long" from bash

Answer (score 7):

`tar --exclude=PATTERN xvzf nameof.tar.gz ./*`

PATTERN can be the directory name. GNU tar.

Comment: If you have part of a file/dir name that matches PATTERN, it will also get excluded from being backed up. This is a little dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may depend on your version of tar.  You can use 'man tar' or 'tar --help' to check for details on your version.  But the options I found are:

tar -X *filename*:  excludes anything listed in the given text file
tar --exclude=*pattern*:  excludes anything matching the pattern